# Laravel Redirects Loop Auth

Tags: loops, authentication, redirect, laravel

i have this in my route.php :

```
Route::resource('post','postcontroller');
```

i want the 'post' can be accessed if the user is login. So, i made this in my route.php :

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'),function(){
Route::get('post','postcontroller@index');
});
```

In my Controller, i coded ->  "after login, redirect to 'post' "

But, when i tried login in real browser, after i login, it automatically redirect to 'login'.

I googled and i got the solution which is i must change the code on filters.php:

FROM

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});
```

INTO

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('post');
        }
    }
});
```

After i done it, it is true that after i tried to login in real browser, it directs me to 'post' url. But, the problem is i got error " This webpage has a redirect loop " (the url has right into 'post').

Is there any solution for the redirect loop problem ? Thanks

Comment: Don't change that filter. The redirect is if a user is not logged in and having `login` there is fine. This looks to me like either your session or authentication in general is not working...

Comment: if i change to 'login' in routes.php, then when i tried to login in real browser, it direct me to 'login' url

Comment: after login to which page you need to redirect ? to post page ?

Comment: Please add the code of your controller that handles the login to your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
Route::resource('post','postcontroller');
```

Causes Laravel to dynamically generate a collection of routes.

Then here you created another route (which was already created by the previous statement)

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'),function(){
Route::get('post','postcontroller@index');
});
```

#### Try this

delete this new single route
<s>Route::get('post','postcontroller@index');</s>

And put the resource into the filter

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'),function(){

    // resource routes now require Authentication to access
    Route::resource('post','postcontroller');

});
```

#### Filter

```php
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});
```

This line `return Redirect::guest('login');` just determines where you will send the user after they fail authentication. so change it to whichever route you want to send them to.

Comment: i've tried it but i still got "This webpage has a redirect loop"